# How to get values from network settings panel?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite, options

I'm using wordpress 3.3. I've created a plugin

My plugin details:

My plugin creates a sub menu under Network settings and create two form fields to define adsense code (200 x 200 ad, 300 x 250 ad).

Here is the screenshot.
[image]
This is my plugin code for network super admin.

http://pastebin.com/88gLTK2a

I'm using this code to print the code in my theme (sidebar).

```
<?php ads1(); ?>
```

and

```
<?php ads2(); ?>
```

But its not working..

When i use the plugin for **normal admins its working perfectly**.
This is the plugin code for normal admins

http://pastebin.com/8KxPDJKA

This is the difference between both versions
http://pastebin.com/diff.php?i=8KxPDJKA

I have no idea why the normal admin version working and super admin version not working.

I tried to print the function plugin itself, its working in network admin.

But its not working when i call it outside the network admin.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong in my code?
Is there any special hook available to retrieve the value outside the network.

**Update:**

functions `ads1(); and ads2();` working. But they are working only within the plugin. I . They actually working. But when i use the same functions in my wordpress theme(sidebar.php) it doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen these?

[get_blog_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blog_option)
[update_blog_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_blog_option)
[delete_blog_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_blog_option)

I'm on a mobile now so I can't re-check this, but my guess is that the option value gets stored in your 'master' blog table and you're trying to access it from a different blog/site. Could that be the case?

Try passing the master blog ID to the functions listed above. Something like:

```
$options = get_blog_option( 1, 'ad_options' );
```

Just a guess though .)